# phonegap build config.xml not working

Tags: cordova

newish to phonegap and trying to make sense of an existing cordova/phonegap project. The bit Im stuck at is the existing config.xml of the project which is below:

I have no idea how this works as its not the standard config.xml. any help appreciated. When I build the project the plugins are not included, namely the softkeyboard plugin. A default config.xml appears to be used instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
<!--
access elements control the Android whitelist.
Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
 -->

<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />

<log level="DEBUG"/>
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
<preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />

<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>    
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>

    <plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="com.WebDevs.SoftKeyBoard" />
</plugins>
</cordova>
```

Comment: In which platform you are building app? Are you using phonegap build (Bd) ? Please share details. Thanks.

Comment: Hi jeek, thanks for your help, Yes I am using phonegap build

Answer (score 0):

please consider this hello world application config.xml. I believe this can be consider as standard config.xml and it must reside at root. [along with index.html]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
    version   = "1.0.0">

 <name>HelloWorld</name>

 <description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
 </description>

 <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
 </author>

 <access origin="*" />
 </widget>
```

Refer this [link](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics)